# Neo4j apoc.cypher.doit succeeds but yields old/previous value

Tags: neo4j, cypher, neo4j-apoc

I'm running a dynamic query where I input a list of properties that contain secrets and remove the secret values from certain nodes.  The query runs successfully, meaning it loops over the list of properties and removes those property values.  However, when the results are yielded, one set of properties shows the old/previous value.  When I run a separate, read-only query on those nodes, I see that the values have indeed been updated.  Am I doing something wrong?

Here's the dynamic list of property names:

```
:params { secretProps: ['semiSecret','superSecret'] }
```

And here's the cypher statement:

```
Unwind $secretProps as prop
With prop
CALL apoc.cypher.doIt('Match (h:History) Where h.'+prop+' Is Not Null Set h.'+prop+' = "[Removed]" Return h;', {}) Yield value
Return value;
```

The nodes returned from the statement above still appear to contain one of the secrets:

```
  {
    "value": {
      "h": {
        "identity": 7040,
        "labels": [
          "History"
        ],
        "properties": {
          "semiSecret": "[Removed]",
          "superSecret": "Oops, this is secret!"
        },
        "elementId": "7040"
      }
    }
  }
```

However, when I check again...

```
Match (h:History) Where h.superSecret Is Not Null Return h;
```

...both secrets have been removed:

```
  {
    "value": {
      "h": {
        "identity": 7040,
        "labels": [
          "History"
        ],
        "properties": {
          "semiSecret": "[Removed]",
          "superSecret": "[Removed]"
        },
        "elementId": "7040"
      }
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Your query returns the `value` returned by each `apoc.cypher.doIt` invocation, and each invocation only changes one property at a time.

So, you would have to filter through at all the returned `value`s to find the last mention of any particluar `History` node to see what its final state is.

Or, more simply, just do a separate read request after the updates are finished, as you have shown.